# Trouble building a select list in razor view using ajax call to mvc controller returning JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

As the title says I am having a bit of trouble with this.  I have succeeded hardcoding the JSON but once I begin to use a model it goes wrong.  Please see what I have to-date below.

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Programs/GetAll', function (data) {

    //clear the current content of the select
    $('#ProgramId').empty();

    //iterate over the data and append a select option
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
    $('#ProgramId').append('<option id="' + key + '">' + val + '></option>');})
    });
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
        var progams = _context.Program
            .Select(a => new
            {
                id = a.Id.ToString(),
                name = a.Name
            }).ToList();

        return Json(progams);
    }
```

Current outcome
[image: It is not handling the returned object]

Current object
[image: Object looks ok]

This hardcoding works with the ajax, js and html.

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> programSelectList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        programSelectList.Add("1", "Bob");
        programSelectList.Add("2", "Cratchett");
        return Json(programSelectList);
        //return Json(_context.Program.ToJson());
    }
```

I am missing something basic, no doubt, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response coming back from your ajax call is an array of items each with an `id` and `name` property. So when you use $.each to loop through them, the variable `val` will be a single js object with those 2 properties. You just need to access those properties to set the option `value` and `text`.

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    $('#ProgramId').append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
});
```

Also, you probably need to specify `JsonRequestBehavior` when returning json data from a GET action method.

```
return Json(progams,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: That's the one!  Thank you, I knew it was something simple I was missing.  Really appreciate the quick response.